# Using Facebook C# SDK to post to page

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've been using the Facebook C# SDK for sometime now, but have a really old version and am still using the REST API (I think). I'm just concerned with using the API to post to my own Facebook page (I have a WCMS plugin that posts content to our institution's Facebook page). I was wondering if anyone knew of a good tutorial on how to get this setup with the latest version of the SDK? I'm also concerned with how this is going to work when offline_access goes away so any thoughts on that would be appreciated as well. I'd rather not have to go in an manually get a new access token every 60 days. This seems somewhat unnecessary since the app I'm using to do the posting is in the same FB account as the page I'm trying to post to.

Comment: an often-overlooked fact is that you do not need offline_access permission to post when a user is offline.  You can post when a user is offline if you use an app access token and you have the publish_stream permission.  You just won't be able to do much else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you start by reading this blog post. http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx

And this documentation http://csharpsdk.org/docs/making-synchronous-requests

Answer (score 12):

Here's one way to do it:

```
    public static string RefreshTokenAndPostToFacebook(string currentAccessToken)
    {
        string newAccessToken = RefreshAccessToken(currentAccessToken);
        string pageAccessToken = GetPageAccessToken(newAccessToken);
        PostToFacebook(pageAccessToken);
        return newAccessToken; // replace current access token with this
    }  

    public static string GetPageAccessToken(string userAccessToken)
    {
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
        fbClient.AppId = "app id";
        fbClient.AppSecret = "app secret";
        fbClient.AccessToken = userAccessToken; 
        Dictionary<string, object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        JsonObject publishedResponse = fbClient.Get("/me/accounts", fbParams) as JsonObject;
        JArray data = JArray.Parse(publishedResponse["data"].ToString());

        foreach (var account in data)
        {
            if (account["name"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("your page name"))
            {
                return account["access_token"].ToString(); 
            }
        }

        return String.Empty; 
    }

    public static string RefreshAccessToken(string currentAccessToken)
    {
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
        Dictionary<string, object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        fbParams["client_id"] = "app id";
        fbParams["grant_type"] = "fb_exchange_token";
        fbParams["client_secret"] = "app secret";
        fbParams["fb_exchange_token"] = currentAccessToken;            
        JsonObject publishedResponse = fbClient.Get("/oauth/access_token", fbParams) as JsonObject;
        return publishedResponse["access_token"].ToString(); 
    }

    public static void PostToFacebook(string pageAccessToken)
    {
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken); 
        fbClient.AppId = "app id";
        fbClient.AppSecret = "app secret";
        Dictionary<string,object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        fbParams["message"] = "Test message";            
        var publishedResponse = fbClient.Post("/your_page_name/feed", fbParams);
    }
```

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you! I was searching all over and only valid answer for me. Nice!

Comment: Might be nice to reference what FacebookClient is ?

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Making-Requests.aspx

and find graph api post

i hope one day prabir and nathan will finish web site docs and we will learn it clearly.for now.just digg the web.